# Apache Nutch - indexing only the modified files in Solr

Tags: solr, nutch

Iam able to set up the Apache Nutch and get the data indexed in Solr. While indexing I am trying to make sure only modified pages gets indexed. Below are the 2 questions we have regarding this.

- Is it possible to tell Nutch to send ‘If-modified-since’ header while
  crawling the site and download the page only if it has changed since
  the last time it was crawled.
- I could see that Nutch is forming the    MD5 digest out of the
  retrieved page content, but even though digest    hasn’t changed
  (compared to previous version), it is still the    indexing the page
  in Solr. Is there any setting with in Nutch to make    sure if the
  content hasn’t changed have it not index in Solr?

Comment: Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261586/recrawl-url-with-nutch-just-for-updated-sites) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14261586/recrawl-url-with-nutch-just-for-updated-sites)

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question here, Hope it helps someone
Once I set the adaptivefetchschedule, could see that Nutch was not pulling the pages that hasnt changed.Its honoring if-modified-since header.